# NLog sublog alternative

Tags: c#, .net, nlog

On the project, I replace Serilog with NLog. In Serilog, I could create several sublogs with my own filters for a separate project. Here is my configuration:

```
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
                .Enrich.FromLogContext()
                .WriteTo.File(...filapath...)
                .WriteTo.Logger(l => l
                    .Filter.ByIncludingOnly(Matching.FromSource<ExceptionMiddleware>())
                    .WriteTo.Email(new EmailConnectionInfo()
                    {
                        FromEmail = fromEmail,
                        ToEmail = toEmail,
                        EmailSubject = subject,
                        NetworkCredentials = credentials,
                        Port = port,
                        MailServer = mailServer,
                    }))
                .WriteTo.Logger(l => l
                    .Filter.ByIncludingOnly(Matching.FromSource("SomeProjectName"))
                    .WriteTo.File(anotherFilePath)
                    .WriteTo.Email(new EmailConnectionInfo()
                    {
                        FromEmail = fromEmail,
                        ToEmail = toEmail,
                        EmailSubject = subject,
                        NetworkCredentials = credentials,
                        Port = port,
                        MailServer = mailServer,
                    }, restrictedToMinimumLevel: LogEventLevel.Error,
                        outputTemplate:
                        "{Timestamp:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff zzz} [{Level}] {Message}{NewLine}{NewLine}{Exception}"))
                .CreateLogger();
```

How can I implement this functionality in NLog? Here is my current configuration of the  file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

    <extensions>
        <add assembly="NLog.Extended" />
    </extensions>
    <extensions>
        <add assembly="NLog.MailKit" />
    </extensions>
    <extensions>
        <add assembly="NLog.Web" />
    </extensions>
    <extensions>
        <add assembly="NLog.Web.AspNetCore" />
    </extensions>

    <variable name="smtp-server" value="smtp-server" />
    <variable name="smtp-port" value="port" />
    <variable name="smtp-password" value="password" />
    <variable name="smtp-authentication" value="Basic" />
    <variable name="smtp-ssl" value="ssl" />
    <variable name="smtp-username" value="username" />
    <variable name="smtp-from" value="from" />
    <variable name="smtp-to" value="to" />

    <targets>
        <target name="fileLogs"
                xsi:type="File"
                fileName="${currentdir}/Logs/log.txt"
                createDirs="True" />
        <target name="mailLogs" xsi:type="Mail"
                subject="subject}"
                body="${message}${newline}"
                from="${smtp-from}"
                to="${smtp-to}"
                smtpUsername="${smtp-username}"
                secureSocketOption="sslOnConnect"
                enableSsl="${smtp-ssl}"
                smtpPassword="${smtp-password}"
                smtpAuthentication="${smtp-authentication}"
                smtpServer="${smtp-Server}"
                smtpPort="${smtp-port}" />
    </targets>

    <rules>
        <logger name="*" levels="Info,Error" writeTo="consoleLogs" />
        <logger name="*" levels="Info,Debug,Error" writeTo="fileLogs" />
        <logger name="*" minlevel="Error" writeTo="mailLogs" />
    </rules>
</nlog>
```

I'm trying to create an alternative to subloger, similar to the Serilog functionality in NLog. More precisely, I am trying to create separate targets for SomeProjectName - file, mail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you see the asterisks in `<logger>` tags? `<logger name="*" .../>`. Those are the filters you're looking for. Every `Logger` object in your code has a name. Loggers created with `LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger()` have the name of the class in which the object was created, including namespaces. But you can call `LogManager.GetLogger(string)` instead, and choose any string for the name. Filters are resolved from first to last, and you can stop the search if the filter is matched with `final` attribute set to true. So, you create a special logger in your code:

```
var log = LogManager.GetLogger("Special");
```

And you use it in configuration, like this (make sure it's before all other rules):

```
<logger name="Special" final="true" writeTo="specialLogFile"/>
```

where "specialLogFile" is defined in `<targets>` section.

In most cases logger name and log level are sufficient to filter all logs. But there is even more powerful filtering feature, with `<filters>` section and `<when>` conditions. Start from [here](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Filtering-log-messages) to learn more about it.